# On the Interval $[0,1]$, the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}x-1,&\text{if }\;x\in\mathbb Q,\\x,&\text{if }\;x\in\mathbb Q^c\end{cases}$ is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I know how to do it for $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, &\text{if }\; x \in \mathbb Q,\\ 0,&\text{if }\; x \in \mathbb Q^c,\end{cases}$$ becuase it's too easy.

But for $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x-1, &\text{if }\;x \in \mathbb Q,\\ x, &\text{if }\;x \in\mathbb Q^c, \end{cases}$$  I am not able to find $U(P,f)$ and $L(P,f)$ where $P$ is a parition of $[0,1]$.

Is there any property that I am missing to prove it?

Answer (score 7):

Write $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 1,& x \in \mathbb Q\\ 0, &x \in \mathbb Q^c\end{cases},\qquad f(x)=\begin{cases} x-1, &x \in \mathbb Q\\ x, &x \in \mathbb Q^c \end{cases}.$$

Note that $f(x)=x-g(x)$. Assume that $f$ is integrable, since $h(x)=x$ is also integrable, we know that $g=h-f$ is integrable. But you have proved that $g$ is not integrable. This is a contradiction. Therefore, $f$ is not integrable.

We have used two properties of Riemannian integrals:

- Any continuous fucntion is Riemannian integrable. The proof uses the uniform continuity property of continuous fucntions defined on closed intervals, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/823000/624428). Here we use this property to show the integrability of $h$. Indeed, for this $h$, the proof will be even simpler.
- Any linear combination of integrable functions is integrable.

### **Added.** The $\epsilon-\delta$ strategy.

*Notations.* We use $\pi:0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=1$ to denote a partition of $[0,1]$, and use $\|\pi\|:=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|x_i-x_{i-1}|$ to denote the mesh of $\pi$.

**Lemma** (*Integrability of $h(x)=x$*). We have
$$\lim_{\|\pi\|\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=\frac12,$$
where $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$ is chosen arbitrarily.

*Proof of Lemma.* Firstly, if $\xi_i$ is the mid-point of $[x_{i-1},x_i]$, i.e., $\eta_i=\frac{x_{i-1}+x_i}2$, then we get a telescoping sum
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \eta_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_{i-1}+x_i}2(x_i-x_{i-1})=\frac12.$$
On the other hand, for arbitrary $\xi_i$, we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{i=1}^n (\xi_i-\eta_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})\right|&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |\xi_i-\eta_i|(x_i-x_{i-1})\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i-1})\\
&\leq \|\pi\|\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})=\|\pi\|\to0,
\end{align*}
as $\|\pi\|\to0$. Combining everything proves the lemma.

Now we prove the non-integrability of $f$. The proof is similar with the proof of the non-integrability of $g$. Recall that both rational numbers and irrational numbers are dense in every interval. For any partition $\pi$, we choose $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$ to be irrational numbers, then
$$\lim_{\|\pi\|\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})=\lim_{\|\pi\|\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=\frac12.$$
However, if we choose $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$ to be rational numbers, then
$$\lim_{\|\pi\|\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n f(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})=\lim_{\|\pi\|\to0}\sum_{i=1}^n (\xi_i-1)(x_i-x_{i-1})=\frac12-1=-\frac12.$$
Therefore, by definition, $f$ is not Riemannian integrable.

Comment: OP wants to show non-integrability using $\epsilon-\delta$ strategy via partitions of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @WangYeFei He asked "Is there any property that I am missing to prove it", so I just told the OP the property he missed: any linear combination of integrable functions is integrable.

Comment: really liked your answer, can you also prove this using $\epsilon - \delta $ strategy

Comment: @SinghNaveen I've added the verbose $\epsilon-\delta$ strategy in the post. As you can see, using some simple properties will surprisingly simplify the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{P}_n=\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$, and notice that

$$M_i=\sup_{x\in[x_{i},x_{i-1}]}f(x)=x_{i},$$

$$m_i=\inf_{x\in[x_i,x_{i-1}]}f(x)=x_{i-1}-1$$

by the fact that each interval of positive length contains both rational and irrational numbers. This gives us that

$$U(f,\mathcal{P}_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})M_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})x_i,$$

$$L(f,\mathcal{P}_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})m_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_{i-1}-1).$$

But notice that the upper sum is also the upper sum of the function $x\mapsto x$, and the lowe sum is also the lower sum of the sum the function $x\mapsto x-1$. As these functions are integrable (and hence their upper and lowe integrals equal their integrals), and as the partition was arbitrary, this means that

$$\overline{\int_0^1} f(x)~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 x~\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$\underline{\int_0^1} f(x)~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 (x-1)~\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

As the upper and lower integrals are not equal, it follows that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.